# How to load .dat file into Oracle database using SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been using the sql loader method to load the .dat file to my database. However, it said I have such error:

> ```
> Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
> ```

so, I was looking for an alternative way to load data into my database. Thanks for your help

Comment: By the looks of it sqlloader can't reach your database. And you can connect with sql-developer to that database?

Comment: yes, I can connect, just don't know why can't use sql loader

Comment: It is a long time since I used an oracle db but back in the days these kind of issues happened when a misconfigured tnsnames.ora or completely different tnsnames.ora was used then you expected. You might try to search on your disk to see if those files are still used today and if so how they are configured compared to sqldeveloper.